# i want to block access to folder and its content php

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

i got folder called recordings on my server and i want to block access from anyone to it and its content and at the same time i want the ability to call the files inside the folder from other pages 
i tried htaccess rule

```
Options -Indexes
```

its just block access to the folder but when i write specific file inside the folder the browser open it and i do not want that
and i tried another htaccess rule :

```
deny from all
```

but it make me not able to call the files on other pages and i want to be able to call them
so can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below rule,

```
<Files ~ "*.php">
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
```